# How to read data from a combobox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I want to read data from a combobox. I know how to this in MySQL and it looks something like this:

```
Private Sub cmbDescrip_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbDescrip.SelectedIndexChanged

 Dim getCategoryDesc As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from category where catDesc=@field2;", connection)

    Dim reader1 As MySqlDataReader

    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()
    End If

    Try
        With getCategoryDesc
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", cmbDescrip.Text)
        End With

        reader1 = getCategoryDesc.ExecuteReader()

        While (reader1.Read())
            txtcatNo.Text = (reader1("catNo"))
        End While

        getCategoryDesc.Dispose()
        reader1.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End sub
```

And yes that code works but now I'm working with sql server 2012, a database I'm not so familiar with. The problem is that sql server does not seem to read the "@field2". In MySQL it does and that's my problem right there. So how do you get it to work with sql server?

Comment: Did you try `debugging`?

Comment: Can you post your SQL Server code?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change your MYSQL command to a SQL command... like below...

```
    Dim getCategoryDesc As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from category where catDesc=@field2;", connection)

    Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader

    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()
    End If

    Try
        With getCategoryDesc
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", cmbDescrip.Text)
        End With

        reader1 = getCategoryDesc.ExecuteReader()

        While (reader1.Read())
            txtcatNo.Text = (reader1("catNo"))
        End While

        getCategoryDesc.Dispose()
        reader1.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```